# Programmatically Add "Start Button" To Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, button

There have been others that have asked this question but the common registry setting that was suggested doesn't work any longer.  What I would like to do is something similar to StartIsBack that "reinvokes" the code to bring the Start Button/Menu back to Windows 8, or I could replicate the work done similar to the other Windows 8 start button alternatives.

Does anyone know how to programmatically (C++ or C#) reinvoke the start button?

Comment: Most of the solutions I've see are actually programs that are pretty smartly designed to mimic the start button - I don't know if there is a way to "reinvoke it" - at least nobody seems to have discovered it yet that I can tell

Comment: Yeah, I was naively hoping there was some API that wasn't be used in Win8 that could be easily called within some code at startup to trigger the button back to life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Win8/2102, Microsoft went through the Windows code to proactively remove all code related to the start button.  I doubt you'll find any APIs left over you could use.